# Issue finding size of dynamic int array that contains a zero

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

**We are not allowed to use vectors.**

Another noobie with a problem. I am trying to find the index of a dynamic int array that is initialized to a size of 50. *We can only use a dynamic int array.*

Say for example I’m only entering 10 integers into this array: 1 9 5 3 8 0 8 2 0 6

The rest of the array is NULL. The goal is to keep the integer values that were entered into this array and put them into an output file. So the size of the array of ints I want is 9. But when I do the following:

```
int index = 0;

    while (intArray[index])
    {
        index++;
    }
```

It tells me that the index is 5 and thus only 5 values get copied into the output file. I know it’s because of the 0 in the array. If there is no 0 in the array, the results come out as expected. How do I bypass this so that the index is correctly reflected as 9 and all the values get copied properly? I appreciate any input!

Comment: I suppose you can't keep the size around when you constructed the array in the first place?

Comment: You could use your own sentinel value as the marker for the end of the array, such as `-1`, or `0x8000000`.

Comment: "The rest of the array is NULL" What does that mean? Maybe it would be easier to show how you initialized the array.

Comment: C strings may be null terminated... but that convention works only because it's assumed the null character will never be a legitimate character in the string.  You can't use that approach in general without deciding on a sentinel value that will never be part of your data, yet is representable in the type you use.  But searching the array for a sentinel to get the length isn't very efficient anyway... it's usually better to just keep track of it with another variable.

Comment: *We are not allowed to use vectors.* -- But nothing stops you from creating a simple class or struct that contains a pointer, a size member, and the requisite member functions.  That's how you thwart these restrictions -- create your own "vector" class, even a minimal one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as NULL for integer value. So there are 3 usual approaches, that used:

1. Special value, marker of the end. This aproach is used for C-style strings, where '\0' used as end. For integer this approach will not work as 0 is "normal" value. You may use some other special value, like `std::numeric_limits<int>::min` or `std::numeric_limits<int>::max`, but this would be not very good approach.
2. Have another variable, that holds current size of array. Note this is usually different, than for how many elements were allocated. This could be wrapped into a class. This is how `std::vector` is implemented.
3. Have another variable, pointer, that points to the pone element after the last one. This could be useful for using in standard algorithms.

Approach 2 and 3 are very close and one can be converted very easy to another. So I would recommend to rewrite your algorithm using start and behind_end iterator:

```
auto end = myArray + 5; // 5 elements in array
for( auto it = myArray; it != end; ++it ) {
    std::cout << *it << endl;
}
```

this code can be easily templatized and used with standard containers.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments the best approach here, given that you cannot use `std::vector` (*sigh*), is to make your own minimal `dynamic_array` (mimicking a `std::vector`) which knows its own size at all times.

It's interface could look something like this:

```
template<typename _Ty>
class dynamic_array {
public:
    typedef _Ty value_type;
    typedef const _Ty& const_reference;
    typedef _Ty& reference;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    //... other necessary typedefs
    dynamic_array() : arr(), arr_size(0), allocated_size(0) {}
    dynamic_array(size_type n) : arr_size(n), allocated_size(n) { allocate(n); }
    ~dynamic_array() { delete arr; }
    size_type size() const noexcept { return arr_size; }
    const_reference operator[](size_type n) const { return arr[n]; }
    reference operator[](size_type n) { return arr[n]; }
    void push_back(const value_type& _val) { 
        ++arr_size;
        // actual implementation of pushing back _val up to you
    }
private:
    value_type* arr;
    size_type arr_size; // number of elements
    size_type allocated_size; // actual number of allocated elements in memory
    void allocate(size_type n) { arr = new value_type[n]; }
};
```

Then to iterate through this via indices you would simply do:

```
dynamic_array<int> darr;
// populate darr
for (int i = 0; i < darr.size(); ++i) {
    // do stuff with each element accessing via: darr[i] as before
}
```

Edit - If you can use `std::unique_ptr` then use this instead of the raw pointer `value_type* arr` to avoid any potential memory management headaches.

Comment: @Hurkyl If he/she cannot use `std::vector` then I doubt `std::unique_ptr` is "allowed" (silly school assignments) either but it would be better indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this only if you are sure that the input data are **not** negatives:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int MyArray[50]; // declare your array

    // ..

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        MyArray[i] = -1; // fill with negatives

    MyArray[0] = 0; // some data
    MyArray[1] = 10; // some data

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        if (MyArray[i] >= 0 )
        {
            std::cout << MyArray[i];
            // write to your file
        }
    }

    //..

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `NULL` is specified to be zero, so this doesn't work any better that OP's code.

Comment: I think you are right, I just tested it. I remember I used to use NULL.. Good catch and thank you. I edited my answer for a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

boost::static_vector would help here. It is essentually a cross between vector and array: either a stack-allocated vector with fixed capacity or uninitialized array with some facilities to track logical size.

Example of use:

```
#include "boost/container/static_vector.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace cnt = boost::container;

void foo()
{
    cnt::static_vector<int, 50> buf = {1, 9, 5, 3, 8, 0, 8, 2, 0, 6,};
    std::cout << buf.size();
}

int main()
{
    foo();   
}
```